# How to retrieve last time stored in column having timestamp with time zone[] as datatype in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a table with below structure and want to fetch last stored datetime. Here in below table column last_updated_date is of timestamp with time zone[] datatype which stores array of timestamps separated by comma. Now I want to fetch last recorded datetime here in this case it should be "2022-06-11 05:13:10.559+00".

```
Table
---------------------------------------

Login

Id

username

login_attempt

last_updated_date timestamp with time zone[]
```

The column last_updated_date has value something similar to this

```
{"2022-01-12 12:14:50.329+00","2022-02-17 03:49:45.525+00","2022-06-11 05:13:10.559+00"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you timestamp array is always stored oldest to latest you can get the index for the latest with the number of entries in the array (array_length). Something like:

```
select Id 
     , username
     , login_attempt
     , last_updated[array_length( last_updated,1)] 
  from login;
```

**NOTE:** Not tested.